# LINQ OrderBy / ThenBy with conditional sorting

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list by date and then by description name, however I need all elements with a certain description to be the top element for each date.

Example:

```
01-02-2014 "Description A"
01-02-2014 "Description B"
01-02-2014 "Description C"
01-02-2014 "Description D"
01-02-2014 "Description E"

02-02-2014 "Description A"
02-02-2014 "Description B"
02-02-2014 "Description C"
02-02-2014 "Description D"
02-02-2014 "Description E"
```

How I need it sorted is by date and description but also all Description B elements at top of list within each date. Like this,

```
01-02-2014 "Description B" <-- Top (Rest below is still sorted ascending)
01-02-2014 "Description A"
01-02-2014 "Description C"
01-02-2014 "Description D"
01-02-2014 "Description E"

02-02-2014 "Description B" <-- Top (Rest below is still sorted ascending)
02-02-2014 "Description A"
02-02-2014 "Description C"
02-02-2014 "Description D"
02-02-2014 "Description E"
```

I've tried doing this with LINQ but I am not sure if it can be done as a single query.

```
return ListOfItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Type)
```

Comment: Since that isn't a natural sort you need to introduce a new property or column where you give priority to the items you want on top. Then you can sort using that value before you sort by the description name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This series of ordering statements will sort it how your example shows

```
return ListOfItems.OrderBy(x => x.Date)
                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.Type == "Description B")
                  .ThenBy(x => x.Type);
```

Answer (score 4):

A more complete solution would be to implement your own IComparer like this:

```
class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == y)
            return 0;
        else if (x == "Description B")
            return -1;
        else
            return (x.CompareTo(y));
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
var sorted = lst.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Description, new CustomComparer()).ToList();
```

This gives you fine control over what condition you consider as having more or less "weight" in the sort.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just add that condition as an intermediate sort order:

```
return ListOfItems.OrderBy(x => x.Date)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.Type == "Description B" ? 0 : 1)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.Type);
```

Comment: Why use a ternary operator? You could have negated with `!=` or just used `ThenByDescending`, both of which are more standard.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce because I don't like having to remember which way true/false are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Without defining a new sort, you could try something like:

```
return ListOfItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.Type == "Description B");
```